# xsl match template by attribute except one

Tags: xslt, xpath

I've a global match on an attribut in my stylesheet but I want to exclude the f - element. How can I do that?

Example XML:

```
<a>
<b formatter="std">...</b>
<c formatter="abc">...</c>
<d formatter="xxx">
    <e formatter="uuu">...</e>
    <f formatter="iii">
        <g formatter="ooo">...</g>
        <h formatter="uuu">...</h>
    </f>
</d>
</a>
```

Current solution:

```
<xsl:template match="//*[@formatter]">
   ...
</xsl:template>
```

I've tried something like this, but that didn't worked.

```
<xsl:template match="f//*[@formatter]">
...
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//f*[@formatter]">
...
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Do you want to exclude the **f** element and all its children, or do want to retain the child nodes (moving them up a level)?

Comment: I only want to exclude the **f** element. The child nodes should be processed "normally".

Comment: Is the attribute of `formatter` in element `f` always `iii`? If yes, you could use that as criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either `//f[@formatter]` or `f[@formatter]` would have worked (the `//` is not necessary). When this XSLT is run on your example input:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[@formatter]">
    <xsl:element name="transformed-{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="f[@formatter]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is:

```
<a>
  <transformed-b formatter="std">...</transformed-b>
  <transformed-c formatter="abc">...</transformed-c>
  <transformed-d formatter="xxx">
    <transformed-e formatter="uuu">...</transformed-e>

      <transformed-g formatter="ooo">...</transformed-g>
      <transformed-h formatter="uuu">...</transformed-h>

  </transformed-d>
</a>
```

As you can see, the `f` is excluded. Does this answer your issue, or have I misunderstood what you want to do?

Comment: nice solution, I think that's what sbo wants. +1